# Is there a tool to reformat paragraph lines in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Most text editors these days contain a feature called Wrap Lines or Reformat Paragraph or something similar that allows you to highlight a block of text and reformat each line so that it wraps at an arbitrary specified length. To my knowledge, there isn't anything like this in the Visual Studio RTM, but is there an extension that adds it? I was unable to find anything via Google. :(

Answer (score 0):

In VS Professional (or above), Edit -> Advanced -> Word Wrap.

This is available at least back to VS 9 (aka VS 2008).

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about. I don't want the editor to visually wrap the text for me. The command I referenced from other text editors takes a block of content and reorganizes the line breaks so that each line is at most N characters long. If necessary, line breaks are inserted to acheive this. This is a permanent edit, not merely a visual presentation.

Answer (score 0):

ReSharper, which can format line wrapping

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html